# ng command throws error; @angular-devkit/core seems to be missing

Tags: angular

I'm a little new to Angular, so apologies if this question has been asked many times.  Certainly, I have found MANY github issues with similar symptoms, but no clear solution (or it's a problem that keeps coming back).

### PROBLEM:

I installed whatever the latest version of Angular comes from npm:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

When I run `ng` (with any options, even if just `ng --version`), I get the following error:

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    ...
    ...
```

### APPARENT SOLUTION:

Installing `@angular-devkit/core` seems to fix the problem:

`npm install -g @angular-devkit/core`

... well, almost...

I then have to make sure I ALSO install the same devkit component **for each application**:

`npm install --save @angular-devkit/core`

### QUESTIONS:

Is there a problem with Angular's packaging?

Do they deliberately leave out the devkit/core component, or just an accident with some versions?

OR, Could it be that I am doing something wrong?

---

**SOFTWARE VERSIONS:**

- Angular CLI: 1.6.4
- Node: 8.9.4
- OS: linux x64
- Angular: 5.2.1

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9276

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, thanks, seems like it's a re-occurring issue, and that specific github issue you referenced seems to suggest it's a new regression... just my luck, the day I start a new Angular project is the day the devkit is broken!

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution, it worked for me.

Comment: angular/cli should not be installed with -g flag. it will corrupt your npm and ruin everything above it's level

Answer (score 19):

Actually, all you need is to add missing `@angular-devkit/core`. For some reason it's missing in the new `ng new` process.

```
npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/core
```

Of course since this is broken in 1.6.0 version you should upgrade your global `@angular/cli` and also your local in the project. This would make more permanent fix. The latest version also fixes missing devkit core dependency:

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@latest
npm i --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 7):

just add "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.28" under your dev dependency and it will work, or you can also execute : `npm install @angular-devkit/core --save-dev`

Answer (score 4):

This error has occurred due to @angular-devkit/core version upgrade in the recent @angular/cli upgrade. Failing version is @angular-devkit/core@0.0.28. So the solution to this is

`npm install @angular-devkit/core@0.0.27 --save -dev`

This is just a patch work until angular team fix this in the next release or so.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, you have to update your @angular/cli to 1.6.5
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.5 and update it in your
project to 1.6.5 (npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.5 --save-dev)

Answer (score 0):

There have been a few builds that have released similar issues from Angular 2-5, I have experienced the same thing with packaging (just a different package). This is an easy fix, **you did it right** by npm installing it.

Just make sure the **Angular Github issues page is aware of this**, if it's not already up. They usually **get fixes out for package issues relatively quickly**.

Answer (score 0):

1. npm update -g @angular/cli
2. editing my package.json changing the line
   "@angular/cli": "1.6.0",
   to
   "@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
3. npm update

This should solve the issue your getting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by following below steps.

1. I upgraded node version to stable 8.11.2.
2. Install angular-cli version 6.0.5

Above steps fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue. But updating your node may fix this. Because my is working when fixed node version.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34451889)